# How to get npm run script run the build:style script when CSS files are updated?

Tags: javascript, npm, tailwind-css

In my package.json I have run scripts that look like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:style":"tailwind build src/styles/index.css -o src/styles/tailwind.css",
    "start": "npm run build:style && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I'm using this tailwindcss framework for CSS, and it uses PostCSS to update the CSS.
Currently if I update my CSS npm doesn't run the build, so my CSS changes are not visible until I stop and re-rerun:

```
npm run start
```

Is there a way for npm to watch the CSS files, and when changed also run the build:style command?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe Tailwinds has a 'watch' feature.  I believe one workaround would be to install the watch package.

```
npm install watch
```

You have a lot of scripts going on and without knowing how you've integrated PostCSS and the likes, it's tough to know exactly what to do. One option would be to create a new script that takes advantage of the new watch node package.

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:style":"tailwind build src/styles/index.css -o src/styles/tailwind.css",
    "start": "npm run build:style && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "watch": "watch 'npm run start'"
  },
```

If that doesn't work, check out the blog below.  It uses the same methodology, but may have insight that could help you figure it out!

https://flaviocopes.com/tailwind-setup/